# PrestaShop - actionOrderStatusPostUpdate Hook: Does It Really Fire When It Should?

Tags: php, hook, prestashop

Good Morning, Stack Overflow!

Quick question. According to the hook documentation (http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5), the hook named "actionOrderStatusPostUpdate" is meant to be fired AFTER the order status of an object has already been changed, if I understand correctly?

Thus, I assumed since the orderStatus has already been changed I could safely change it again in my code without any issues. My code contains a conditional block that scans the products in the order the moment it goes to the "Payment Received" status, and if the order contains any "restricted items" it would notify the user and change the order status to "Restricted: (reason)" (ID: 15). When I run the code and the hook fires, I end having the status set and then immediately replaced with "Payment Received".

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc4ebr2ybytx2ks/Screenshot%202016-03-15%2012.52.47.jpg

Is this normal behaviour for the POST update hook? Since the status is supposed to ALREADY BE CHANGED, why would it change it anyway?

```
...
} else {
//  Restricted order...
    $order->setCurrentState(15, 1);
...
```

I have also tried this:

```
...
$history = new OrderHistory();
$history->id_order = (int) $order_id;
$history->changeIdOrderState(15, (int) $order_id);
...
```

Is there another way to do this that I can ensure it changes correctly?

**EDIT**

I am aware of this question that asks the same thing: [Prestashop - Change order status when payment is validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408612/prestashop-change-order-status-when-payment-is-validated?rq=1), but it is also yet to be answered and is thus of no help to me.

**EDIT**

The best I can do is to try and explain to logical flow of the code:

1. When the user or anything else changes the status of an order, the hook fires (hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate) from the module.
2. If the status of the order is "Payment Accepted" continue to the next section, otherwise, do nothing...
3. I then check the order, delivery address, and products in the order for certain flags that I use to mark the order "Restricted" (this includes delivery address, invoice address, certain product features, etc)
4. If the order is restricted a case is created in another system that the company can contact the customer to resolve the restriction after this is done the order should set to order state: "Restricted" (id. 15) to indicate that a restriction applies.
5. If the order is NOT restricted, it's passed along to different system for processing, etc.

Comment: which payment module are you using ?

Comment: The code is agnostic to the payment module, since it's running on the Post Order State Change hook, but for testing, I just use "bank wire"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prestashop - Change order status when payment is validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408612/prestashop-change-order-status-when-payment-is-validated)

Answer (score 0):

The hook `actionOrderStatusPostUpdate` is executed inside the function `OrderHistory->changeIdOrderState()` at the very end.

So if you are changing your `order status` with the function `OrderHistory->changeIdOrderState()` (which also includes email sending, stock management etc.), the hook `actionOrderStatusPostUpdate` will be executed.

If you want just to change the ID of the `order status`, you can use some code like this:

```
$order = new Order((int)$id_order);        
$order->current_state = (int)$id_order_state;
if ($order->update() && $order->setCurrentState((int)$id_order_state))
{
    // proceed
}
else
{
    // report error
}
```

Comment: When running the above code, completely nothing happens now. Dumping the Order object reveals that the Order Status had in fact changed, but the back office is not reflecting the change...

Comment: Implemented the code, but no go...it still does the same thing. Sets "Restricted" and THEN "Payment Accepted". So on the orders page, the status still reads "Payment Accepted" :/

Comment: ...THEN "Payment Accepted" - So what is wrong? The last assigned status is shown.

Comment: Yes..."Payment Accepted" is shown, I need "Restricted" to be shown. See, the moment the status BECOMES "Payment Accepted" the hook fires, does what it needs to do, and if a restriction exists, it must CHANGE the order status to "Restricted: <reason>", but it sets Restricted first, and then Payment Accepted, thus the order status reads "Payment Accepted" not "Restricted".

Comment: You should share a bigger part of your code, where you are assigning "Payment accepted" status.

Comment: I never assign the "Payment Accepted" status in my code, the hook fires WHEN that status is assigned in the back office. Basically when order state is changed to "Payment Accepted" the hook fires and runs the code, I attempt to overwrite this assignment WITHIN that hook when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Besides, I'm not allowed to share too much of the code, it's company policy. XD

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you without seeng the logic you are using. All code is not neede, just to understand the steps you are taking.

Comment: Usually `hookActionOrderStatusPostUpdate` is used and it works.

Comment: I will place an explanation of the logic in an edit :)